# This relationship is hard to prove vs be proved

Tags: grammar

Hi I'm learning English as a second language and there was a sentence in my grammar book

> Although this relationship is hard to [prove/be proven],....

I know the answer is 'prove' but I don't get the reason. In the sentence, isn't "this relationship " the subjective? If so, shouldn't it be written in a passive state? My teacher said that there's something about the word "hard" that makes the answer "prove" and I can relate to that, but I can't think of a clear reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

> If so, shouldn't it be written in a passive state?

It shouldn't be active or passive, because it's modifying an adjective (*hard*) so the infinitive *to prove* is used. (The *is* here is active).

You were comparing "prove" with "be proven" but in fact you should have been comparing "to prove" with "be proven" (or perhaps "to be proven").

An interesting almost-counter is "this relationship is yet to be proven". This seems like a counter example, but it is actually a different form because it's in the past tense (*yet* includes a time-relationship in its meaning) and so the "to be proven" passive infinitive is used.

Comment: I'm not sure if ***yet*** qualifies as an "adverbial of frequency", but paraphrasing as *not even once up until now* suggests it might be. Noting *frequently to be seen, always to be remembered, never to be heard, sometimes to be found*, it seems to me with other such adverbs we can delete ***to be*** with no significant change in meaning, but we can't do that with ***yet***. But there's also something about ***prove***, because although *already to be found* is okay with/without ***to be***, *already to be proven* doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?